# SP 2013 adding users to SP group through API not giving permissions

Tags: javascript, api, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm using the SharePoint 2013 API to add users to a groep 'Site eigenaren', which means they will get full control on a site.
After calling the API, they are visible in the UI in the SP group, but they don't get the permissions of the group.

When I remove them through the UI from the group and add them again using the UI, they get the permissions.
Is there anything else that has to be done when adding a user through the API?

My code to add a user:

```
function addUserToGroup(contextWebInfo, groupName, username) {
        console.log('Adding ' + username + ' to group ' + groupName);
        return fetch(currentSiteUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname('" + groupName + "')/users", {
            headers: new Headers({
                Accept: 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                'X-RequestDigest': contextWebInfo.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue
            }),
            credentials: 'include',
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.User' }, 'LoginName': 'BIJTJES\\' + username })
        }).then(function (response) {
            if(response.ok){
                console.log('User ' + username + ' added to group ' + groupName);
            }else{
                alert('Er is een fout opgetreden. Gelieve een melding op de SelfServiceDesk aan te maken met volgende tekst: Op site "' + currentSiteUrl + '" komt de foutmelding "' + response.error.message.value + '" bij het toevoegen van een lid aan de groep "' + groupName + '" als gebruiker "' + username + '"'); 
            }
        }).catch(function (error) { console.error('Error getting data:::', error); });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm this issue, and I can confirm this is also an issue when using `JSOM` instead of `REST`.
Turns out the issue is when SharePoint is using claims. This means that if you give the REST api the user login ID (domain\user) it will do exactly that.
But if you add "`i:0#.w|`" to the user ID `("i:0#.w|domain\user")`, everything works.